# Is this a convenient way of running code in a background thread and return a result via a callback executed in the calling thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

In the last days I have found myself using this approach for asynchronously performing some long operation (several seconds), and then return some value via a callback that must execute on the caller thread, which is typically **but not necessarily** the UI thread.

```
public abstract class DoSomethingCallback
{
    public abstract void done(Object result);
}

public void doSomething(final Object param, final DoSomethingCallback doSomethingCallback)
{
    // Instantiate a handler for the calling thread
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    // Start running the long operation in another thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do a long operation using "param" as input...
            Object result = longOperation(param);

            // Return result via a callback, which will run in the caller thread
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doSomethingCallback.done(clearBytes);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This seems to work pretty well and is very simple to use. However, I somehow suspect it might have some problems I'm not aware of. So the question is, **what are the potential issues of this approach?** What are better alternatives than manually creating and running a thread? I'm seeking for simplicity and robustness.

Comment: what is wrong with `AsyncTask`

Comment: @tyczj I'm guessing that's what is meant by: "*which is typically **but not necessarily** the UI thread*". Doesn't `AsyncTask` work solely with the UI thread?

Comment: sorry, I remove my comment, I was clearly wrong :) (I was saying there is no need for the caller thread to be UI, well it should be)

Comment: use AsynTask, it's far better than thread

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that such approach breaks encapsulation: the second thread not only computes the result, but also dictates what the caller thread should do with it. So I'd better refactor your code as follows:

```
public abstract class DoSomethingCallback {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    public void post(final Object result) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSomethingCallback.done(result);
            }
        });
    }

    public abstract void done(Object result);
}

public void doSomething(final Object param, final DoSomethingCallback doSomethingCallback) {
    // Instantiate a handler for the calling thread
   final DoSomethingCallback handler = new DoSomethingCallback () {
      void done(Object result) {
        ...
      }
   };

   // Start running the long operation in another thread
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // Do a long operation using "param" as input...
           Object result = longOperation(param);

           // Return result via a callback, which will run in the caller thread
           handler.post(result);
        });
      }
    }).start();
 }
```

Comment: There are some errors in the code: the variable `doSomethingCallback` is unused, and the `DoSomethingCallback` class should be instantiated by the caller, and not inside of the method. I'll +1 if you fix it. But anyways I'm guessing what you're trying to do, it sounds like a good idea to consider, thanks.